# Codeigniter Validation Rules - Can they be set from the model, or is this bad practice?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, model, validation

With CodeIgniter you can use the built in form validation class, which basically allows you to run a POST input against a set of rules for each field. The issue is though, that the validation rules are generally always set in the controller.

Surely this means if more than one controller is accessing the specific table (via its model), you're going to have to have an additional copy of the validation rules in another controller.

Because of this, wouldn't it be better to set the validation rules in the model, and then load them from there?

Unless I'm missing something completely here? Just seems a bit of an odd way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a config file for this sort of situation, and load relevant name upon `->run('name')`.

[See documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#savingtoconfig)

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to set your rules in a config file: /application/config/form_validation.php